# Parsing an optional list of ranges

Tags: python, argparse

My script needs to take an option followed by a list of pages, specified as comma-separated list of ranges, and to process the expanded list of pages. So, for instance,

```
script.py -a 2,4-6,9,10-13
```

should get the list

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

to work with. Currently I am doing this:

```
import argparse

def getList(argument):
    ranges = list(argument.split(","))
    newRange = []
    for theRange in ranges:
        subRange = list(map(int, theRange.split("-")))
        if (len(subRange) > 1):
            newRange.extend(range(subRange[0], subRange[1] + 1))
        else:
            newRange.extend(subRange)
    newRange.sort()
    return newRange

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--pages", type=getList, dest="pages", default=[], help="pages to process")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

and it works but I'm relatively new to this Python thing and was wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Edit: I fail to see why it was marked as a duplicate question. *None* of the answers to the questions it was marked as a duplicate of does exactly what I have described above. The idea is *not* to process a simple list of space- or comma-delimited arguments but something more complex - a list of ranges that have to be expanded.

Comment: I agree, neither of those is a good duplicate.  They didn't read your question.  But if this processing works, it's a good solution.  A custom `type` is the only way to do this in `argparse`.

Comment: As long as your users aren't tempted to split up the numbers with blanks this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution.  It's not necessarily the best.  In particular, there is probably a  more performant version involving chained iterators rather than nested iterators.

Given:

```
>>> range='2,4-6,9,10-13'
```

You could do something like:

```
>>> result = [range(int(y[0]), int(y[1])+1) 
... for y in [(x.split('-') + [x])[:2]
... for x in r.split(',')]]
```

Which gets you:

```
>>> result
[[2], [4, 5, 6], [9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

If we unpack those comprehensions, the innermost one iterates over:

```
>>> range.split(',')
['2', '4-6', '9', '10-13']
```

The second is:

```
>>> result = range.split(',')
>>> [(x.split('-') + [x])[:2] for x in result]
[['2', '2'], ['4', '6'], ['9', '9'], ['10', '13']]
```

The expression `(x.split('-') + [x])[:2]` is ensuring that we have a two-item list, even for single numbers, so that we can pass that to the `range` function.

Finally, we iterate over that result:

```
>>> [range(int(y[0]), int(y[1])+1) for y in <the result from the rpevious operation]
```

Which is hopefuly obvious.  Given the list `[2, 2]`, we call `range(2, 3)` which gives us `[2]`.  Applied across all the results from the previous operation, this gets us the result we saw earlier:

```
[[2], [4, 5, 6], [9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

And now your problem is "how do I flatten a list", to which one solution (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)) is:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(result))
[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: I guess you meant `r` instead of `range` in your first line of code. Also, your solution (as well as mine) has the problem that the user might specify stupid ranges (duplicated, overlapped, etc.). I guess the easiest way to handle that is to convert the list to a set and then back to a list.